# preventing new data snapshot from creating additional child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send data snapshots to Firebase database. Which is mostly working fine, but I am having an issue where, instead of child objects being attached directly to their intended parents, they are being added to an additional child that is attached to the intended parent.

```
public void CreateCampaign()
{
   campaignName = campaignNameText.text;
   ownerName = pInfo.userName;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(campaignName))
   {
      DebugLog("invalid campaign name.");
      return;
   }

   DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to add campaign ", campaignName, ownerName));

   DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Users").Child(pInfo.userName).Child("Campaigns").Push();

   DebugLog("Running Transaction...");

   reference.RunTransaction(AddCampaignTransaction)
     .ContinueWith(task =>
   {
      if (task.Exception != null)
      {
         DebugLog(task.Exception.ToString());
      }
      else if (task.IsCompleted)
      {
         DebugLog("Campaign " + campaignName + " added successfully.");
      }
   });
}
```

```
TransactionResult AddCampaignTransaction(MutableData mutableData)
{
   List<object> Campaigns = mutableData.Value as List<object>;

   if (Campaigns == null)
   {
      Campaigns = new List<object>();
   }


   Dictionary<string, object> newCampaignMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   newCampaignMap["CampaignName"] = campaignName;
   newCampaignMap["Owner"] = pInfo.userName;
   newCampaignMap["Members"] = 0;
   Campaigns.Add(Child(newCampaignMap));

   mutableData.Value = Campaigns;

   return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);

   InitializeCampaign();
}
```

So with this all my data is added to the database, however my data structure looks like this.

- Users

  - User Name

    - Campaigns

      - pushID

        - 0

          - Campaign Name
          - Owner Name
          - Memebrs

What i need to know is; how can I prevent the child "0" from being placed between pushID and the three keys I'm adding, so that my data structure looks like this.

- Users

  - User Name

    - Campaigns

      - pushID

        - Campaign Name
        - Owner Name
        - Members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in [Gazihan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697348/3068190), the problem arises from uploading a list (Campaigns) to the database and not the node you desire (newCampaignMap).

Transactions are used where you need to modify data that already exists on the server in a ordered fashion. Because of your use of `Push()` to generate a **new** database reference, this is not needed and `SetValueAsync` can be used instead.

In your code for `AddCampaignTransaction` above, you generate an empty list (because there is never existing data), add the value of `newCampaignMap` to that list and then upload the list to the database instead of just the new value. In this function, you are also making use of shared internal variables from the `CreateCampaign` function which is bad practice, especially when dealing with asynchronous code.

Instead, I propose using the following code:

```
public void CreateCampaign()
{
    // take local copies of values
    string campaignName = campaignNameText.text;
    string ownerName = pInfo.userName;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(campaignName))
    {
        DebugLog("invalid campaign name.");
        return;
    }

    DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to add campaign '{0}' for '{1}'... ", campaignName, ownerName));

    // structure data
    Dictionary<string, object> newCampaignMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    newCampaignMap["CampaignName"] = campaignName;
    newCampaignMap["Owner"] = pInfo.userName;
    newCampaignMap["Members"] = 0;

    DebugLog("Adding to database... ");
    // get reference and upload data
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Users").Child(pInfo.userName).Child("Campaigns").Push();
    reference.SetValueAsync(newCampaignMap)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            DebugLog(task.Exception.ToString());
            return;
        }

        DebugLog("Campaign " + campaignName + " added successfully.");
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect, not only does it solve my issue but it simplifies the code considerably making it a lot easier to work with. It also provides me with a little insight as to things to watch out for in general, thanks again sir

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a `List` with a single element. The 0 signifies that it is the 0th element. If there were more elements in the `List`, you would see 1, 2, etc.

You should replace this line

```
mutableData.Value = Campaigns;
```

with this line

```
mutableData.Value = newCampaignMap;
```

and try again.

Also you can get rid of the Campaigns etc. that are not used anymore.